# $(0,1)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but not of $\mathbb{R}^2$, when we think of $\mathbb{R}$ as the x-axis in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Prove this.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

It's problem #1 of Chapter 2 in Pugh's book.  I think I got the first part by taking $r=1$ and pointing out that $d(p,q) < 1 \implies q \in (0,1)$ for all $p \in (0,1)$ but I have no idea how to show it isn't a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  I tried proof by contradiction and got no where.  I've been working at this problem for hours and not getting anywhere.  How should I do it?

Comment: If your space is $X$, is $X \setminus (0,1)$ an open set? Using the open space topology, if $X \setminus A$ is open for some set $A$, then $A$ is closed. If you derive the definition for a closed space topology, how does this change? What does $X \setminus A$ look like for different types of sets of $A$?

Comment: @Brandon I'm in your class

Answer (score 5):

Your argument for the first part is incorrect: $d(p,q)<1$ and $p\in(0,1)$ do **not** imply that $q\in(0,1)$. For example, take $p=\frac12$ and $q=\frac54$; then $d(p,q)=\frac34<1$, but $\frac54\notin(0,1)$. Try this instead: if $p\in(0,1)$, let $r=\min\{p,1-p\}$, and show that if $d(p,q)<r$, then $q\in(0,1)$. (Note that $r$ is simply the distance from $p$ to the nearer endpoint of $(0,1)$.

For the second part, observe that if $B$ is any open ball whatsoever centred at a point of $(0,1)\times\{0\}$, there are points of $B$ with positive $y$-coordinates; thus, $B$ cannot be a subset of $(0,1)\times\{0\}$. And if $(0,1)\times\{0\}$ contains no open ball, it can’t be open in $\Bbb R^2$. (In particular, if $B$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $\langle x,0\rangle$, where is $\left\langle x,\frac{r}2\right\rangle$?)

Comment: Thanks!  So for the first part, my argument so far involves looking at the cases d(p,q)=|p-q| < p and d(p,q)=|p-q| < 1-p and just doing absolute value operations to show it.  Is that the right way?

Comment: @Brandon: You’re welcome! You could do that, but it might be easier to realize that $\{q:d(p,q)<r\}$ is simply the open interval $(p-r,p+r)$ and then show that if $r$ is defined as I suggested, then this interval is always a subset of $(0,1)$.

Comment: Thanks!  I actually just finished my absolute value argument though.  It basically is just rearranging the inequality for both cases, dividing by -1, and showing that in the first case p < 1/2 and in the second case p > 1/2, then the inequality simplifies to 0 < q < 1.

Comment: Let $r=\min\{p,1-p\}$.  If $d(p,q) = |p-q| < p$, then $-p < p-q < p$ and $-2p < -q < 0 \Rightarrow 0 < q < 2p$.  $p < 1/2$ because if $p>1/2$, then $r$ would equal $1-p$ because $1-p$ would be less than p.  Thus $0 < q < 2(1/2)=1$.

Similarly, if $d(p,q) = |p-q| < 1-p$, then $-(1-p) < p-q < 1-p$ and $-2(1-p) < p-q < 0 \Rightarrow 0 < p-q < 2(1-p)$.  $p > 1/2$ because if $p < 1/2$, then $r$ would equal $p$ because $p$ would be less than $1-p$.  Therefore $1-p < 1/2$ and $0 < q < 2(1/2)=1$.

Comment: @Brandon: Looks good to me.

Comment: Wait, I think there's an arithmetic error in the second part.  I did $-2(1-p) < p-q < 0$ and forgot to subtract 1-p from the middle term.

Comment: @Brandon: So you did; I checked the first half and didn’t look all that closely at the second. You should get $0<1+q-2p<2-2p$, so $q<1$. And $q>p-(1-p)=2p-1\ge 0$.

Comment: Thanks!  I fixed it.  So for $\mathbb{R}^2$, <x,r/2> is just going to be in $\mathbb{R}$ right because r=0?  But isn't $\mathbb{R}$ a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @Brandon: But $r>0$: we’re looking at a **non-empty** open ball centred at $\langle x,0\rangle$, so the radius $r$ must be positive. In particular, $\frac{r}2>0$, so the point $\left\langle x,\frac{r}2\right\rangle$ is not on the $x$-axis. // No, $\Bbb R$ is not a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. Elements of $\Bbb R^2$ are ordered pairs of real numbers; elements of $\Bbb R$ are real numbers, and a real number is not an ordered pair of real numbers. What **is** true is that there is a natural map between $\Bbb R$ and the subset $\Bbb R\times\{0\}$ of $\Bbb R^2$, the set that we often call the $x$-axis.

Comment: ... The correspondence is of cours $x\mapsto\langle x,0\rangle$, and it’s even an isometry with respect to the usual metrics, but it doesn’t make $\Bbb R$ itself a subset of $\Bbb R^2$; it just picks out one of many subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ that ‘behave like’ $\Bbb R$ in every respect that we care about at the moment.

Comment: Ah okay thanks!  That makes sense with the subset stuff.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Brandon: You’re welcome! Glad it made sense.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in (0,1)\times \{0\}=L$, can you show that $B(x,\epsilon)$ is not contained in $L$ for any $\epsilon >0$? Note the ball is now a circle, not an open line segment!

To prove it is open in $\Bbb R\times \{0\}\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ note any segment $(a,b)\times \{0\}$ is of the form $B(x,\epsilon)\cap(\Bbb R\times \{0\})$ for a suitable $x$ and $\epsilon >0$.

Recall that $G$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ iff for each point in $G$ there is an open ball around such point contained in $G$. On the other hand, $G'$ is (relatively) open in $S\subseteq \Bbb R^2$ iff it is of the form $G\cap S$ for some open set $G$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: Ah okay.  I wasn't sure if I was allowed to do the Cartesian product with 0 because the problem didn't say anything about it.  So this is an epsilon proof?  Do I have to do the first part (open in $\mathbb{R}$) using an epsilon argument, or was my explanation fine?

Comment: @peter -- why do we need to include the point 0? if you take any x in (0,1) and consider a disk of any radius about it, some of that disk cannot be in (0,1) because it will be above or below the x axis.